# Rails 4 limit association by attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a complex nest of associations due to a project that requires highly configurable permissions.  The model highlights are

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :group_membership
    has_one :group, through: :group_membership

    has_one :group_permission, through: :group, source: :group_permissions

    enum role: [:group_leader, :user]
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :group_memberships
    has_many :users, through: :group_memberships

    has_many :group_permissions
end

class GroupPermission < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :group
end

class GroupMembership < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :group
    belongs_to :user
end
```

A `GroupPermission` has a `group_id`, a `role`, and an `allowed_actions` for that `role`.

So for each `Group`, there can be multiple `group_permissions` with differing `allowed_actions` depending on `role`

I want to be able to say `@user.group_permission` and have it return the `group_permission` scoped to `@users`'s `role` but I'm not sure if that's achievable through the associations alone

**Update**

I guess another way to ask this question is, if I define a method on `User` such as

```
def group_permissions
    group.group_permissions.where(role: role)
end
```

That gives me the correct `group_permissions` record for this user.  I'd like to be able to do this with an association, and I'm not sure if that's possible

Comment: I've never seen a `has_one, through:` association before. I'm 99% sure you don't need the `GroupMembership` model and instead change it to `belongs_to :group`. However, about your question: I don't know why you would need a scope since it's a `has_one` relationship.

Comment: I think you're probably correct about `GroupMembership` being unnecessary.  As is, when I run `@user.group_permission` I get the incorrect record back, as it pertains to a `User` with a role of `group_leader` while `@user` has a role of `user`

Comment: Can you post your code where you call `@user.group_permission`?

Comment: Sure.  I'm working with Pundit and inside a policy I say `user.allowed_to? :action`.

In the `User` model
    `def allowed_to?(action);
        group_permissions.allowed_actions? action;
    end`

`allowed_actions?` is a bitmask as provided by the bitmask_attributes gem.

Sorry about the formatting, not sure what I'm doing with the mini-markdown

Comment: No problem. Just next time edit your post to include big chunks of code.

Comment: I've never used Pundit or bitmask_attributes, so I'm not really sure what to tell you. So you don't call `@user.group_permission` directly?

Comment: Not directly within the policy.  Effectively, that's what gets called though.  `user.allowed_to? :foo` just reads better within the policy.  Thanks for the help though, it's appreciated